# Creating character vector with comma separator and without double quotes in R using paste command

Tags: r, quotes

Desired result:

```
s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10
```

I want to get a character vector with comma separator and without double quotes using `R` `paste0` command. MWE is given below:

```
noquote(paste0("s", 1:10))
```

Could not figured out how to append comma between two elements of the character vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `collapse` parameter with `paste` to concatenate to a single comma separated string.

```
paste0("s", 1:10, collapse=",")
[1] "s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10"
```

## Demo