# break string into element of vector

Tags: r

I have run the following R code to combine char 'group' with a sequence of number

```
paste0('group', seq(1, 5))
```

the output is

```
"group1" "group2" "group3" "group4" "group5"
```

how to make the results be a vector or list, like the following?

```
c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4", "group5")
```

Comment: What is difference between your input (`paste0('group', seq(1, 5))`) and expected output (`c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4", "group5")`) ? If you check using `identical`, you get output as TRUE, `identical(paste0('group', seq(1, 5)), c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4", "group5"))`

Comment: You want commas? Isn't it already a vector? On phone so can't tell.  I think you're just confused about how R prints vectors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating character vector with comma separator and without double quotes in R using paste command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43961411/creating-character-vector-with-comma-separator-and-without-double-quotes-in-r-us)

Comment: If you want to output the R command to create the object in that style, use `dput`, e.g., `dput(paste0('group', 1:5))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code:

```
c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4", "group5")
```

... and the code:

```
  paste0('group', seq(1, 5))s
```

.... would create an object whose print output would look like:

```
[1] "group1" "group2" "group3" "group4" "group5"
```

The logical test function `is.vector` returns TRUE:

```
> is.vector( c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4", "group5") )
[1] TRUE
```

And the value of your code and the target are "identical" according to the most stringent test available:

```
 identical( paste0('group', seq(1, 5)) ,  c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4", "group5"))
[1] TRUE
```

So there is no "how". You already have the means in your code.

(You should understand that "vector" in R terminology means an object with no attributes other than names. Sinple lists are TRUE under the `is.vector` test.)